# Unir diccionario y lista con el método por comprensión

Tags: python, python-3.x

Muy buenas, estoy empezando a aprender Python y me encuentro con un pequeño ejercicio que no logro resolver con listas por entendimiento como se me indica: tengo:

```
A = [2718768, 1299633, 973132, 908263, 663173] 
B = {1: 'Roma ', 2:' Milán ', 3:' Nápoles ', 4:' Turín ', 5:' Palermo '}
```

La idea es crear un nuevo diccionario donde podrían ser la clave de la enumeración y los valores de los nombres de las ciudades y los números de la lista . . Se supone que usar

```
C = {clave: valor para d en (A, B) para clave, valor en d.items ()}
```

¿podría hacerlo pero no comprendo como, si me pueden ayudar? Gracias

Comment: Hola @Cafepoetica Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow. Por favor procura incluir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para ver lo que estas intentando hacer o para entender mejor tu problema. Te invito a que revises las recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Lo que buscas es una explicación de los métodos de compresión?

Comment: Nota lingüística: El término inglés es "list comprehension", que se puede traducir como "comprensión de listas", pero no "entendimiento de listas" (y menos aún "compresión", pues no tiene que ver con comprimir). Comprensión viene de comprender, pero en el sentido en que una lista "está comprendida por" varios elementos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿podría hacerlo pero no comprendo como, si me pueden ayudar?

La expresión,

```
C = {clave: valor para d en (A, B) para clave, valor en d.items ()}
```

es una [expresión generadora](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). Quiere decir que los valores del objeto al que se le asigna son producto de una iteración. Ejecutando esta expresión con respecto a tu código, se consigue:

```
C = {clave: valor for d in (A,B) for clave, valor in B.items()}

{1: 'Roma ', 2: ' Milán ', 3: ' Nápoles ', 4: ' Turín ', 5: ' Palermo '}
```

**Nota:** Se cambia `d.items()` por una `B.items()` para que sea válida.

**Por qué se obtiene este resultado:**

Paso por paso, `for d in (A,B)`. La variable `d` toma el valor de los elementos de la tupla `(A,B)`, `d` itera sobre ambos objetos. Luego `for clave, valor in B.items()`, `clave` y `valor` toman el valor de las tuplas que devuelve `dicc.items()`, por lo tanto `clave` es la clave del diccionario que se está generando dentro de `C` y `valor` el valor de esta clave. Ahora la parte `clave: valor` del principio tiene más sentido.

Esta compresión es un poco compleja, voy a intentar poner un ejemplo básico. Queremos que una lista tenga como elementos los números del 1 al 10, lo común sería hacer esto:

```
lista = []

for item in range(1,11):
    lista.append(item)

print(lista)
```

Salida:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Con una expresión generadora se simplifica esta tarea:

```
lista = [item for item in range(1,11)]
print(lista)
```

Misma salida:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Esto ocurre por que a `lista` se añade `item` y el valor de `item` está definido por la iteración del rango de los números del uno al 10 (1 al 11, hay que tomar en cuenta que `range()` no toma el último número).

**Un buen ejemplo:**

La compresión de tu ejercicio implica dos iteraciones y tres valores, jugando con la lista `A` y el diccionario `B` se puede lograr `C` sea:

```
C = {i + 1: [B[i+ 1],A[i]] for i in range(len(A or B))}
print(C)
```

Salida:

```
{1: ['Roma ', 2718768], 2: [' Milán ', 1299633], 3: [' Nápoles ', 973132], 4: [' Turín ', 908263], 5: [' Palermo ', 663173]}
```

Con la iteración de `i` sobre el rango de la longitud de `A` o `B` se construye `C`.

Espero que te haya quedado claro y haberte ayudado, saludos!

Comment: wow! genial explicado!! mil gracias!!!

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides aceptarla presionando la palomita y puntuarla como buena. ;)

Comment: ok es la primera vez y no sabía, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema se resolvería de *manera normal* así:

```
C = {}
for i, j in B.items():
    C[i] = [j, A[i-1]]

print(C) # {1: ['Roma ', 2718768], 2: [' Milán ', 1299633], ...}
```

El mismo código usando compresión de listas:

```
C = {i: [j, A[i-1]] for i, j in B.items()}
```

Advertencia - Se asume que los keys de `B` son consecutivos y que la cantidad de elementos de `A` son `>=` que los de `B`. Si cambian esas condiciones, hay que crear algo más avanzado.

Comment: ok! muchas gracias